# Does the top plate of a capacitor hold half of the capacitor's charge or all of it?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, conventions, definition

I am a little confused conceptually about the charge of a capacitor held by the top plate. Is it equal in magnitude to $q$, or is it half of $q$? It makes more sense to me for it to be half of $q$, with the other half existent on the other plate, but I am thinking this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The charge of a capacitor is the magnitude of $q$. The charge of one plate is $+|q|$ and the other plate has the charge $-|q|$.

Answer (score 1):

When we say that the charge of a capacitor is $Q$, we mean that one plate has charge $Q$ and the other plate has charge $-Q$.

That is to say, we don't mean that the capacitor has a *net* charge of $Q$ (as I suspect you might be thinking) since, in fact, the *net* charge of a charged capacitor is *zero*.

By *charged*, we mean the capacitor has stored *energy* in more or less the same sense of a *charged* battery.